# Python fails to recognize a digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file such as this and the program removes everything but the hindi text.

```
1
00:00:10,240 --> 00:00:13,824
विकास नाम का एक गरीब मजदूर था

2
00:00:14,592 --> 00:00:15,360
जो सेठ

3
00:00:15,616 --> 00:00:16,896
भीमसेन के यहां
```

Here is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re
import string
import codecs

def del_brackets(s):
        a = re.compile(r'\<.*?\>')
        result = a.sub('', s)
        return result.strip('\n').strip()

def del_brackets2(s):
        a = re.compile(r'\[.*?\]')
        result = a.sub('', s)
        return result.strip('\n').strip()

def del_brackets3(s):
        a = re.compile(r'\{.*?\}')
        result = a.sub('', s)
        return result.strip('\n').strip()

def del_brackets4(s):
        a = re.compile(r'\(.*?\)')
        result = a.sub('', s)
        return result.strip('\n').strip()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

outfile = open(sys.argv[1].replace('.srt', '.txt'), 'w')

exclude = set('♪"#$%&\()*+-/:<=>@[\\]^_`{|}')
for line in lines:
#   print(repr(line))
    line = line.strip()
    #line = unicode(line.strip('\n'), 'utf-8')
    if len(line.strip()) != 0 and line != 1 and line != "1":
        if (not line.isdigit()) and ('-->' not in line):
            line = del_brackets(line)
            line = del_brackets2(line)
            line = del_brackets3(line)
            line = del_brackets4(line)
            line = ' '.join(''.join(' ' if ch in exclude else ch for ch in line).split())
            line = re.sub(r'\.\.\.', ' ', line)
            outfile.write(line.lstrip() + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

and the expected output is below

```
विकास नाम का एक गरीब मजदूर था
जो सेठ
भीमसेन के यहां
```

However, my program doesn't recognize the first line digit, and instead it returns

```
1
विकास नाम का एक गरीब मजदूर था
जो सेठ
भीमसेन के यहां
```

Why does this program doesn't recognize the digit when I specifically wrote 1 or "1"?

Comment: What output do you see from `print(repr(line))` for the line with `1` on it?

Comment: So why the if:     if len(line.strip()) != 0 and line != 1 and line != "1": ?

Comment: @Stefan so if they are not 1 the program will skip it but my program doesn't skip the line

Comment: @JohnGordon i see '\ufeff1'

Comment: Cannot reproduce: If I paste this text in a file called `file.srt` and the code in a file called `code.py` and I run `python3 code.py file.srt` then a file called `file.txt` is written which contains the expected output without the `1`. I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: If the output of repr is `'\ufeff1'`, then there's more than just `1` on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex we can create a simple expression that covers the three cases that you want to ignore:

1. timestamp line
2. number line
3. empty line

From there we can use python's built-in `filter` method to filter out all of the undesired lines, and use the `filter` results as the lines to write.

```
import sys, re

def pruneSRTtoTXT(fn):
    fn2    = fn.replace('.srt', '.txt')
    stamp  = '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}'
    ignore = re.compile(f'^({stamp}\s-->\s{stamp}|[0-9]+|[\r\n]+)$', re.M)

    with open(fn, 'r') as f, open(fn2, 'w') as f2:
        f2.writelines(filter(lambda l: not ignore.search(l), f.readlines()))

pruneSRTtoTXT(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: because the text itself might contain numbers that we want to keep.

Comment: @Yuri Burkov - OK, I wrote a completely different method